# Battleships Grid changes after coordinate is selected c#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to c# and I've been asked to create a Battleships game. Currently I'm trying to create a way so when a coordinate is typed in, the grid will change from 0 to either "H" preferably to indicate its been hit.

GRID

```
                    for(Column = 0; Column < gridSize; Column++)

                    Console.Write(grid[Column, Row] + " ");

                // Ship 1

                grid[Convert.ToInt32(numbers1), Convert.ToInt32(numbers2)] = Destroyer1;

                grid[Convert.ToInt32(numbers1), Convert.ToInt32(numbers2) + 1] = Destroyer1;

                grid[Convert.ToInt32(numbers1), Convert.ToInt32(numbers2) + 2] = Destroyer1;

                grid[Convert.ToInt32(numbers1), Convert.ToInt32(numbers2) - 1] = Destroyer1;Console.WriteLine("Cordinate Y:");
```

COORDINATES

```
            var temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Cordinate X:");

            var temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (grid[temp, temp1] == Destroyer1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HIT!");

                Hit++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MISS!");
            }
```

I'm not quite sure how I would achieve this, but what I want to happen is when the coordinates match the ones entered in by the player it changes the grid location from 4 (the ships value) to "H" and when it doesn't match it replaces 0 (the grid value) to "M". Does anyone know how i can do this? I've attached the code for grid and the code if its a hit or miss etc.

Comment: What is `Destroyer1`? Is it a string?

Comment: Destroyer1 is an int with the value of 3, numbers1 and numbers2 are strings, the values are calculated from a list and then converted into an int and plotted on the grid. Gird is an Int too, here is the code used int[,] grid = new int[gridSize, gridSize];

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the ship data and the hit/miss data separately:

- A separate table; or
- Make the original table contain pairs `(bool isShip, bool? hitMiss)`.

I hope the following example is hopeful.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var ships = new uint[8,8]; // 0 = no ship, 1 = ship
    ships[0,0] = 1;
    ships[0,1] = 1;
    ships[0,2] = 1;
    ships[0,3] = 1;

    var tries = new uint? [8,8]; // null = not tried, 0 = miss, 1 = hit

    var exampleShots = new (uint X, uint Y)[]{(1,1), (0,1)};

    foreach(var shot in exampleShots) 
    {
        if( CheckAndMarkShot(ships, tries, shot.X, shot.Y) ) 
            Console.WriteLine("Hit");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Miss");
    }
}

static bool CheckAndMarkShot(uint[,] ships, uint?[,] tries, uint x, uint y)
{
    if( tries[x,y] != null ) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("$(x,y) has aleardy been tried");
        return tries[x,y] == 1;
    }

    var isHit = ships[x,y] == 1;
    tries[x,y] = isHit ? 1U : 0;
    return isHit;
}
```